# Dynamic ByRef The best overloaded method match for ... has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have an application that is built on top of dynamic and reflection types.

```
dynamic obj = null;
obj = My_Assembly.CreateInstance("full.namespace.class");
obj.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
obj.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
obj.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;
.....
myservice.Add(ref obj, false);
```

Runtime raises an exception that The best overloaded method match for ... has some invalid arguments

I did a trick to see whats wrong...

```
var objd = (full.namespace.class)obj;
myservice.Add(ref objd, false);
```

and it works fine. To see what's difference I ran a quick match in immediate window

```
? obj == objd;
true
```

and the result was true which means both are identical.

Can anyone explain me whats wrong with it?

Comment: Can you show us the overloads of the `.Add()` method you are using? Pretty sure `.Add()` is seeing an `object` in the reflection code, but in your manual code it's seeing the derived type. Also I assume in your "I did a trick" code you meant to reference `ref objd`, not `ref obj`, yes?

Comment: Reflection is seeing the same class as in the exception details its mentioning same class. 

Below is my service code

    public class myservice : .....
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public void Add(ref full.namespace.class obj, bool overwrite)
    {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }

Comment: Why this code does not throw the same error at compile time? **ref dynamic** cannot be converted to **ref full.namespace.myclass**. In any case, it should be possible to call the Add method using reflection, because the parameter type at runtime matches the method signature. Try this: myservice.GetType().Invoke("Add", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, myservice, new object[] { obj, false }).